# How to calculate the sum of values for one day in excel

Tags: excel

I need to sum up the values in column M for every day. I tried following function:

```
=IF(D2<>D3;SUMIF(D:D;D3;M:M);" ")
```

However this doesn't sum up the correct value and I don't see where I went wrong.

In cell O5 I used the regular SUM(M2:M5) function to show what value I'm looking for. The sheets consists out of 35041 rows so I'm trying to find a function which makes the sum of daily value's for every day of the year.

[image: Screenshot of worksheet]

Comment: Can you use a pivot table?  Or do you need the result in a column?

Comment: I need the result in a column. It might be possible to use column D since that column already shows a value of 1 for day 1, value 2 for day 2 etc. I also need to use the same function to make a sum of the values Mi per month (maybe use column C)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula or method you use to achieve the values in column D is obviously wrong. It shows 1 instead of 31 for 31/12/2017.

If you get column D working properly (e.g. `=day(a2)` filled down) the formula in N5 would be,

```
=if(d5<>d6, sumif(d:d, d5, m:m), "")
```

You can check the correct total with a sumifs.

```
=if(day(a5)<>day(a6), sumifs(m:m, a:a, ">="&int(a5), a:a, "<"&int(a5)+1), "")
```

For a month-to-month, use EOMONTH to get the first and last day of a month.

```
=if(month(a5)<>month(a6), sumifs(m:m, a:a, ">="&eomonth(a5, -1)+1, a:a, "<"&eomonth(a5, 0)+1), "")
```

Comment: This is data I received from the government. Column D counts it as the first day of the year (+ an hour from the day before). I tried replacing it by =day(a2) as you said, however now I get a value of 77,6369428 where it should be 0,5176368

Comment: You need to try the sumifs I provided or create a sumifs that uses columns B, C and D not just column D.

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks a lot! If I now want to calculate a summation per month, do I just need to replace day(a5)<>day(a6) by month(a5)<>month(a6) ?

Comment: month(a5)<>month(a6)` is part of it but you would need to change the criteria as well. I'll see if I can make a modification above.

Comment: The function for the month returns a date (i.e. 0/01/1900 for row 5 - month1, 4/02/1901 for row 2981 - month2). Any idea how I can get this to a sum of the values for column M ?

Comment: I just tested the formula added above and it seems to work well.

Comment: Weird.. I entered this exact formula in O5 : =IF(MONTH(A5)<>MONTH(A6); SUMIFS(M:M;A:A; ">="&EOMONTH(A5; -1)+1;A:A;"<"&EOMONTH(A5; 0)+1); "") and I still get the return "0/01/1900". Could it be that I use a different version of excel ? I also have to change every ',' with ';'

Comment: That was it! I now have everything I need, you have no idea how long I've been trying to fix this on my own. Thanks again for your time and help, Sir, Madam!